# Why Eclipse removes "Build Automatically" flag?

Tags: java, eclipse, build

I'm using Eclipse for J2EE development, many times when I open the IDE the "build automatically" flag is not flagged. I cannot understand why.
Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Any mechanism in your setup that synchronizes the workspace with your teams? The flag is stored in ".metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs" in the workspace folder.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, nor have I heard of someone having the same issue. In the preferences, is _Oomph > Setup Tasks > Preference Recorder_ enabled? Which additional plugins do you have installed? Is your workspace directory synchronized and have you checked the file permissions of the file mentioned by @k5_ (e.g. when you have run - which you should not do - Eclipse as admin)?

Comment: Couldn't find any property such that on Linux, Eclipse 2021-06. `find .metadata -name '*.prefs' -print0 | xargs -r0 grep 'build'`

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1722751/#msg_1722751

Comment: The flag appears on `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` only when it's false: `description.autobuilding=false`

Comment: @LMC Only the settings that differ from the default value are saved, which is in your case `false`. Default settings can differ between IDE packages (products) and can be customized (via `-pluginCustomization`).