# Eclipse Build Automatically not retained across Eclipse restarts

Tags: eclipse, build

The workspace setting for building automatically starts in an unchecked state and even if I check it and apply the settings, if I restart Eclipse it shows unchecked again. My workspace has been migrated through several iterations of Eclipse, but it is frustrating. I have tried with and without the -clean in the eclipse.ini. I'm running on an M1 MacBook with latest OS 13.3.1 (a)

My current version is:
Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)
Build id: 20230309-1520

And, if I check for updates none are available.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on exactly the same setup. Is there a `description.autobuilding=false` value in the `org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` file in the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` folder in the workspace?

Comment: Which additional plugins do you have installed?

Comment: Already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68970545/6505250) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73322866/6505250).

Comment: @greg -- there was no item for description.autobuilding so I've tried adding it set to true to see if that helps.

Comment: the flag mentioned by @greg is getting set when eclipse is starting. I've tried deleting the line as well as setting it to false but something in Eclipse's startup is explicitly setting it to false. I may try making the file read-only...

Comment: Even setting to read-only fails as the file gets overwritten somehow with the description.autobuilding=false

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could resolve this was to perform a clean installation of the 2023-03 version of Eclipse. I saved the old installation if anyone would want to look at it. Thank you for the comments.